# How to use URL(string: someConstant) with declared constant in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I'm newbie in Xcode (Swift 3).

Why this code **works**:

```
let someUrl = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
```

But this one **returns error**:

```
let someConstant = "https://www.apple.com"
let someUrl = URL(string: someConstant)
```

> *Cannot use instance member 'someConstant' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available*

Comment: There's no guaranteed order for properties declared in a class to be initialized, so they can't reference each other in their own initialization.

Comment: Please [search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Cannot+use+instance+member+within+property+initializer%3B+property+initializers+run+before+%27self%27+is+available) before posting.

Comment: What is the error you getting can you explain in detail?

Comment: @dan, I understood what you mean, but what is the right way? How can use constant in URL()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is not exactly in your code and not with the object URL. but it depends where you placed the code.

you placed it at `Place A` where it becomes static variables. and thats why you can not access your someConstant at this place from an other instance variable. if you place your code snippet in a function `methodName` ( `Place B`) your code snippets work. for your case it is enough to place just `let someUrl = URL(string: someConstant)` at `Place B`

```
class a {

    // Place A: instance constant here


    func methodName(){

      // Place B
    }
 }
```

see also: [more results at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+Cannot+use+instance+member+within+property+initializer%3B+property+initializers+run+before+%27self%27+is+available)